# What's the benefit of using dynamic programming (backward induction) instead of applying global minimizer

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, dynamic-programming

I'm interested in multistage optimization problems.

Let's take for example the following [paper](http://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww2.isye.gatech.edu%2F~nemirovs%2Frob_portf.pdf&ei=OtX0U8OfI8jOOaqpgeAB&usg=AFQjCNHkJmuyt88kzk85A2cWTVYdH2vPxQ), there we have a optimization problem of the form:

$$\max \sum_{i=1}^{n+1}r^L_ix_i^L$$

such that

$$ x^l_i=r^{l-1}_i x_i^{l-1}-y_i^l+z^l_i,\hspace{2pt} i=1,\dots n,l=1,\dots,L$$
$$ x^l_i=r^{l-1}_{n+1} x_{n+1}^{l-1}+\sum_{i=1}^n(1-\mu^l_i)y_i^l-\sum_{i=1}^n(1+\nu_i^l)z^l_i$$
$$y^l_i\ge 0,\hspace{2pt} i=1,\dots n,l=1,\dots,L$$
$$x^l_i\ge 0,\hspace{2pt} i=1,\dots n,l=1,\dots,L$$
$$z^l_i\ge 0,\hspace{2pt} i=1,\dots n,l=1,\dots,L$$
where some $x_i^l$ is the value (in dollar) of an asset $i$ at time $l$, $r_i^l$ is the asset return, $y^l_i$ and $z^l_i$ are the amount of asset sold and bought. $\mu^l_i $ and $\nu_i^l$ have also economical interpretation, but are not that important for the question. Assuming everthing is deterministic, we can solve this problem using interior points / simplex method since it is an "simple" LP. On the other hand I think one could solve this via dynamic programming approach. What would be the advantage or disadvantage of this? Does the situation change if I apply a "utility function" $f$(convex let's say), i.e.

$$\max \sum_{i=1}^{n+1}f(r^L_ix_i^L)$$

Many thanks for the insights.

Answer (score 1):

Usually dynamic programming methods (if applicable to the problem - in your question its applicable) are faster than LP methods.